# why or how we lose few messages when i restart my kafka broker?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I m running kafka in single node ,i want to see the kafka Producer behavior when i shutdown my kafka broker then i restart my broker in few secondes,so i create spring boot projet where i might to send 1000 customer JSON object and print the offset of the JSON object sended everytime.
My application works fine but when i shutdown my kafka broker and after few second i Restart my broker ,my producer return to send the  objects from the latest offset normally.
The problem that for my example when the offset = 983 in the console ,i down my kafka and when i start my broker again, i see that kafka start sending messages from **offset =984** but i find that 3 or 4 messages are lost with this message error!!!

```
983
offset acked
2019-04-01 16:20:34.635  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:34.638  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1910675333, epoch=31) to node 0: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
2019-04-01 16:20:34.689  WARN 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-04-01 16:20:34.844  WARN 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-04-01 16:20:35.050  WARN 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2019-04-01 16:20:35.557  WARN 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
.........
dali 36
2019-04-01 16:20:55.592  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:55.594 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:55.594  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:55.696  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:55.696  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
984
offset acked
985
offset acked
986
offset acked
987
offset acked
988
offset acked
989
offset acked
990
offset acked
991
offset acked
992
offset acked
993
offset acked
994
offset acked
995
offset acked
996
offset acked
997
offset acked
998
offset acked
999
offset acked
1000
offset acked
1001
offset acked
1002
offset acked
1003
offset acked
1004
offset acked
2019-04-01 16:20:55.799  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:55.803 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:55.803  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:55.904  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:55.904  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.006  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.010 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:56.011  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.111  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.111  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.213  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.215 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:56.215  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.317  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.317  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.419  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.422 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:56.422  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.523  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.523  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
dali 37
1005
offset acked
2019-04-01 16:20:56.625  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.628 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:56.628  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.729  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.729  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.831  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.834 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:56.834  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:56.936  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:56.936  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.037  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.040 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:57.040  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.140  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.141  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.245  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.252 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:57.252  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.358  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.358  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.460  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.466 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:57.467  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.567  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.568  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
dali 38
1006
offset acked
2019-04-01 16:20:57.671  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.681 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: This is not the correct coordinator.
2019-04-01 16:20:57.681  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.785  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.786  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2019-04-01 16:20:57.889  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Discovered group coordinator dali-X556UJ:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2019-04-01 16:20:57.896 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2019-04-01 16:20:58.007 ERROR 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Offset commit failed on partition jsa-kafka-topic-0 at offset 984: The coordinator is loading and hence can't process requests.
2019-04-01 16:20:58.125  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Revoking previously assigned partitions [jsa-kafka-topic-0]
2019-04-01 16:20:58.125  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [jsa-kafka-topic-0]
2019-04-01 16:20:58.125  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] (Re-)joining group
2019-04-01 16:20:58.149  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Successfully joined group with generation 31
2019-04-01 16:20:58.149  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=jsa-group] Setting newly assigned partitions [jsa-kafka-topic-0]
2019-04-01 16:20:58.154  INFO 7656 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [jsa-kafka-topic-0]
dali 39
1007
offset acked
dali 40
1008
offset acked
dali 41
1009
offset acked
dali 42
1010
offset acked
dali 43
1011
offset acked
//...continue to send normally
```

Why my messages with **offset=1004** and **offset=1005** andd **offset=1006** and the first message with **offset=983**(when i down my broker) failed to be send when i start my kafka broker again.

//my main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringKafkaSendConsumeJavaObjectApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner run(CustomerRepository personRepository) {
    return args -> {
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    list.add(new Customer("dali "+i, 25, "homme"));
    Runnable runnable = new MyRunnable(list,producer);
    runnable.run();
    };
 }
```

this is my run method where i send one customer every ONE second

```
       public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRunnable.class);
private List<Customer> customers;
private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

public MyRunnable(List<Customer> customers,KafkaProducer kafkaProducer) {
    this.customers = customers.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    this.kafkaProducer = kafkaProducer;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    customers.forEach(customer -> {
        System.out.println(customer.getName());
        kafkaProducer.send(customer);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);//1second
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }); 

}
```

//this is my send method

```
        @Service
 public class KafkaProducer {
private static final Logger LOGGER=LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, Customer> kafkaTemplate;

@Value("${jsa.kafka.topic}")
String kafkaTopic = "jsa-test";

@Async
public void send(Customer customer) {
    //LOGGER.info("sending data= '{}' " , customer);
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,Customer>> listenableFuture =  kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic ,customer);
    listenableFuture.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String,Customer>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println(throwable.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final SendResult<String, Customer> message) {
            System.out.println(message.getRecordMetadata().offset());
            System.out.println("offset acked");

        }

    });
}
```

//this is my kafka config in application.properties

```
#Kafka Cluster
jsa.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
#consumer group id
jsa.kafka.consumer.group-id=jsa-group
#topic name
jsa.kafka.topic=jsa-kafka-topic
#server port
server.port=9000
#reconnect.backoff.ms=10000
#Integer.MAX_VALUE
retries=2147483647
retry.backoff.ms=1000
#5 minutes
request.timeout.ms=305000
#Integer.MAX_VALUE
max.block.ms=2147483647
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to wait for the `Future<?>` returned by the `KafkaTemplate.send()` method, or call `kafkaTemplate.flush()` before stopping your app.

**KafkaProducer.flush() Javadocs**

```
/**
 * Invoking this method makes all buffered records immediately available to send (even if <code>linger.ms</code> is
 * greater than 0) and blocks on the completion of the requests associated with these records. The post-condition
 * of <code>flush()</code> is that any previously sent record will have completed (e.g. <code>Future.isDone() == true</code>).
 * A request is considered completed when it is successfully acknowledged
 * according to the <code>acks</code> configuration you have specified or else it results in an error.
 * <p>
 * Other threads can continue sending records while one thread is blocked waiting for a flush call to complete,
 * however no guarantee is made about the completion of records sent after the flush call begins.
 * <p>
 * This method can be useful when consuming from some input system and producing into Kafka. The <code>flush()</code> call
 * gives a convenient way to ensure all previously sent messages have actually completed.
 * <p>
 * This example shows how to consume from one Kafka topic and produce to another Kafka topic:
 * <pre>
 * {@code
 * for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record: consumer.poll(100))
 *     producer.send(new ProducerRecord("my-topic", record.key(), record.value());
 * producer.flush();
 * consumer.commit();
 * }
 * </pre>
 *
 * Note that the above example may drop records if the produce request fails. If we want to ensure that this does not occur
 * we need to set <code>retries=&lt;large_number&gt;</code> in our config.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Applications don't need to call this method for transactional producers, since the {@link #commitTransaction()} will
 * flush all buffered records before performing the commit. This ensures that all the {@link #send(ProducerRecord)}
 * calls made since the previous {@link #beginTransaction()} are completed before the commit.
 * </p>
 *
 * @throws InterruptException If the thread is interrupted while blocked
 */
@Override
public void flush() {
```

Comment: So, in order to avoid loosing messages, the producer needs to wait for the kafka ack (needs to have acks=all) and also have retries>0 configured to be able to try again?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments on old answers. Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)