# Java Spring Kafka Template producer lost messages on broker restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using spring-boot (2.1.6.RELEASE) with spring-kafka (2.2.7.RELEASE) and I'm sending messages to my kafka cluster using KafkaTemplate. But sometimes (usually when I restart a kafka-broker or do a rebalance) I see errors like this when I'm sending messages :

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition.
```

Due to the default Kafka producer configs, I expect send failures to be retried but they are not. Default Kafka producer configs:

```
retries: 2147483647  (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#retries)
acks: 1               (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#acks)
```

My config is this:

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs()
    {
        // See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs for more properties
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Long, String> producerFactory()
    {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Long, String> kafkaTemplate(KafkaTemplateProducerListener<Long, String> kafkaTemplateProducerListener,
                                                     ProducerFactory<Long, String> producerFactory)
    {
        KafkaTemplate<Long, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
        kafkaTemplate.setProducerListener(kafkaTemplateProducerListener);
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
```

and I'm sending messages like this:

```
kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, key, body);
```

I have searched all over the internet and everyone says that this configuration with the retries and acks must work but it doesn't. What I'm missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spend some time debugging this I found the solution:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
```

For more information about this property: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#acks



Very good blog showing different scenarios that you can lose messages in kafka:

- part 1: https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/14/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-kafka-cluster-part1
- part 2: https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/9/18/how-to-lose-messages-on-a-kafka-cluster-part-2

**Side note** - from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459296/why-or-how-we-lose-few-messages-when-i-restart-my-kafka-broker) answer I found out that it is good idea to use this if you don't want to lose messages on shutdown:

```
@PreDestroy
public void flush()
{
    kafkaTemplate.flush();
}
```

Comment: What's the default `ACKS_CONFIG`?